# Combine output from df -h /dev/xvda1 into a single line

Tags: sed, awk, disk-usage, cut

I want to convert the 2 line output from `df -h` into a single, meaningful line i.e.

Take

```
[root@ip-10-42-1-246 tmp]# df -h /dev/xvda1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       20G  1.2G   19G   6% /
[root@ip-10-42-1-246 tmp]#
```

And produce 1 line to read

```
Filesystem: /dev/xvda1 Size: 20G Used: 1.2G Avail: 19G Use%: 6% Mounted on: /
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this? I can then squirt the signle line into syslog and do Interesting Stuff with it.

Comment: IMHO if you're going to squirt to `syslog`, don't bother with the labels. Add them later on when you do the "interesting stuff".

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
LANG=C df -h /dev/xvda1 |
awk 'NR>1{print "Filesystem: "$1 " Size: " $2 " Used: " $3 " Avail: " $4 " Use%:" $5 " Mounted on: " $6}'
```

Comment: Yeah, I've got a few variations around that, but it doesn't give me the exact format. Imagine that I might want to put it through a TTS synth, so that it could be read or understood by a non-technical person.

Comment: POST changed for a awk command

Comment: @freecloud , this method is returning exactly what you have asked for. If this is not the format you need, then what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You might do...

```
findmnt -DP /dev/xvda1
```

Which is pretty close to what you want. Here's what my `/dev/sda1` gets:

```
findmnt -DP /dev/sda1

SOURCE="/dev/sda1" FSTYPE="vfat" SIZE="3G" USED="306.5M" AVAIL="2.7G" USE%="10%" TARGET="/esp"
```

You can optionally specify the fields further with the `--output` switch.